# Plot four curve with one x axis and 2 different y axis on the same plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

By using matplotlib, I want to plot train accuracy, validation accuracy, train error and validation error through time. x axis is the number of iteration for all curves. I want to reserve left x-axis for accuracy values and right y-axis for loss values and then, plot all four on the same figure.

To do that, I tried several things, at the end I couldn't arrived at the point that I want.

Could anyone can help me on this?

My code (did not work as I want):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
ax.plot(e_t_x, e_t_y, label="ERROR TRAIN", color='r')
ax.set_ylabel("Error", color="r")

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="2", frame_on=False)
ax1.plot(e_v_x, e_v_y, label="ERROR VALIDATION", color='g')
empty_string_labels = [''] * len(e_v_y)
ax1.set_xticklabels(empty_string_labels)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="3", frame_on=False)
ax2.plot(a_t_x, a_t_y, label="ACC TRAIN", color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel("Acc", color="b")
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="4", frame_on=False)
ax3.plot(a_v_x, a_v_y, label="ACC VALIDATION", color='c')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to make like that (but instead of 3, I have 4 curves) (I took the image from here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/why-could-an-overfitted-cnn-model-have-a-higher-validation-accuracy)

[image: taken from: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/why-could-an-overfitted-cnn-model-have-a-higher-validation-accuracy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only two axes.  ax2 has to be the twin axis of ax1. You can plot as many plots as you want on each axis.  See the following code where sin and cos are plotted on the left y-axis whereas cubic and quadratic are plotted on the right y-axis:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
fig.suptitle("title")
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
sinx = [math.sin(angle) for angle in x]
cosx = [math.cos(angle) for angle in x]
ax1.plot(x,sinx, label = 'sin')
ax1.plot(x,cosx, label = 'cos')

quadratic = [num**2 for num in x]
cubic = [num**3 for num in x]
ax2.plot(x,quadratic, color='green', label = 'quadratic')
ax2.plot(x,cubic, color='red', label = 'cubic')

ax1.set_ylabel("sin, cos")
ax2.set_ylabel("quadratic, cubic")

ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left')
ax2.legend(loc = 'upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]